# show image as selected on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have made a code on clicking which I am getting the image which I have selected but that image is not looking as selected, only on hover it looks as selected but as soon as hover is removed from the image it doesn't show image as selected

```
<CardActionArea  value ="car" onClick={this.handleCardClick}>
       <img src={Car} alt="Car" width="80%" height="80%"/>
</CardActionArea>
```

"I am expecting the output in which on clicking image it should be seen as selected image"

Comment: show handleCardClick we cant help if you dont show how you are attempting to change the component/img

Comment: handlecardclick is just a function in which am passing event nothing other than that

Comment: Then why would you expect the image to change in anyway if none of your code changes it

Comment: Add a state to called selected and toggle the value in the handlecardclick function call. And use this state to conditionally insert a class to the components. And style the components by adding a border

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
<CardActionArea className=`${ isSelected?'selected':'' }`  value ="car" onClick={this.handleCardClick}>
       <img src={Car} alt="Car" width="80%" height="80%"/>
</CardActionArea>
```

and write a **.selected** CSS class to highlight it and set isSelected = true on click.

**EDIT: I just read the docs. the className prop does very little You should do this instead.**

```css
.CardActionArea {
  border: none;
}
.CardActionArea.selected {
  border: 5px solid #333
}
```

and then you need to

```
<CardActionArea selected classes={{ root: 'CardActionArea', selected: 'selected' }} value ="car" onClick={this.handleCardClick}>
       <img src={Car} alt="Car" width="80%" height="80%"/>
</CardActionArea>
```

Then just use a condition with isSelected as stated before the edit to toggle the selected prop

[Here is the Docs where the example is given](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#pseudo-classes)

Comment: this is not working...Is there any other alternative of cardactionsarea? actually cardactionarea I 've taken from material UI

Comment: Try it on the <img> then

Comment: I tried but that too not working on removing hover it gets removed

Comment: @AilleySmith I have edited the answer and you can add as many pseudo-classes to the classes prop as you want.